# Matching words that end in any number of digits OR "X"

Tags: regex

Trying to match all of these:

```
{_someWord1} ... $1=someWord, $2=1
{_another82} ... $1=another, $2=82 (item in question)
{_testX}     ... $1=test, $2=X
```

My regex: `{_(\w+)(\d+|X)}` matches all three, but the groups for the 2nd item are:

```
{_another82} ... $1=another8, $2=2
```

I'd like to be able to have any number of digits be in `$2`, and keep just the words in `$1`. Do I need to have a look ahead of some sort?

Comment: Please provide your programming language/environment with any regex-related question, since regex flavors can differ significantly.

Comment: Just in case, note that `\w` covers A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most regex flavors, you could use [ungreedy repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), which consumes as little as possible (as opposed to the default - as much as possible):

```
{_(\w+?)(\d+|X)}
```

However, if the part before the digit, can never contain digits and underscores (which are included in `\w`) you could simply use a more specific character class:

```
{_([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+|X)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a non-greedy match (adding a `?` after `\w+`) to consume as little as possible and still match:

```
{_(\w+?)(\d+|X)}
```

or if your language (unspecified) supports look-arounds, then:

```
{_(\w+)(?<=[a-zA-Z])(\d+|X)}
```

which asserts that the last character of group 1 must be a letter (although letters may appear elsewhere within group 1)